# Error no ifopmnwrp in java library path when deploying oracle forms 12.2.1.4 in Oracle Linux 8

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

When trying to deploy the forms application version 12.2.1.4, I receive this error, does anyone know what is causing it?

The nodeManager if deployed correctly, as well as the weblogic administration server and the reports server, also works correctly, only the deployment of the forms server fails.

I was trying to implement forms in Oracle Linux 8
[image: this is the erorr]

Comment: Unfortunatly the screenshot is too small to read so I have no idea what the error/exception says.

Before trying to install, did you ensure that the OS was properly configured?  Specifcally, have all the required OS packages (and versions) been installed?  https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.4/sysrs/system-requirements-and-specifications.html#GUID-37C51062-3732-4A4B-8E0E-003D9DFC8C26__LINUX8  

Also, what do you mean the "deployment of Forms fails"?  Are you manually trying to deploy the Forms Servlet?  This is done automatically during Domain creation.